# Page loading is too slow Jquery and external Amazon Images file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, amazon-web-services

I have a web page which is loading more than 1000 images per page and these images are located on Amazon severs.

I have added jQuery plugins to this page which are local to the webserver, I am not using any remote JS or CSS.

When the page is loaded for the first time or refreshed the page looks distorted and images are overlapping each other. When the content is fully loaded or cached the page displays correctly.

Is there is a way to load the images in a way that will make the page look good during loading?

Answer (score 0):

Display gif images while original image is loading.
Try
[jQuery Image Loader](http://mycodeprograms.blogspot.in/2012/10/how-to-add-loader-while-page-load.html)

or
http://bradsknutson.com/blog/display-loading-image-while-page-loads/